# PHP CURL PUT from file path

Tags: php, curl, put

I'm trying to do a CURL PUT with a file but I'm having issues.

Here is my code:

```
$url_path_str = 'http://my_url';
$file_path_str = '/my_file_path';

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, ''.$url_path_str.'');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PUT, 1);

$fh_res = fopen($file_path_str, 'r');
$file_data_str = fread($fh_res, filesize($file_path_str));

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILE, $fh_res);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, filesize($file_path_str));
fclose($fh_res);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$curl_response_res = curl_exec ($ch);
```

The script keeps timing out and I'm not sure why.

I'd appreciate some assistance. Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I figured this out. It happened to be fclose that was causing the issue. I simply put it after curl_exec.

Here's the amended code:

```
$url_path_str = 'http://my_url';
$file_path_str = '/my_file_path';

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, ''.$url_path_str.'');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PUT, 1);

$fh_res = fopen($file_path_str, 'r');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILE, $fh_res);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, filesize($file_path_str));

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$curl_response_res = curl_exec ($ch);
fclose($fh_res);
```

Hope this is helpful to someone else later.

Cheers.

Comment: $file_path_str = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\LithiumChat\Setting.png';
i gave path like that .. i gave me error directory not found.  
on line $fh_res = fopen($file_path_str, 'r');
then i gave like that 
http://localhost/LithiumChat/Setting.png.. 
then it give me error curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, filesize($file_path_str));
that http not allowd what to do

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure this is the problem, but the only one I can see is that you are reading the contents of the file with `fread()` when you don't need to, and are not doing anything with the data. This will leave the pointer at the end of the file, and cURL will be waiting for data from the pointer that it will never get.

Remove this line and see if your still have the problem:

```
$file_data_str = fread($fh_res, filesize($file_path_str));
```

Alternatively, if you do actually need the data from the file and are using the `$file_data_str` variable later in the script, place this line immediately after the one mentioned above:

```
rewind($fh_res);
```

**EDIT**

Also, I'm not sure about this at all: `''.$url_path_str.''` - you should just be able to do this `$url_path_str` and it will have the same effect but be (slightly) more resource-efficient.

Comment: Ok I edited the script to add rewind i.e. `$fh_res = fopen($file_path_str, 'r');
$file_data_str = fread($fh_res, filesize($file_path_str)); rewind($fh_res);` but I still have the same problem.

Comment: Is the problem that the PHP time limit is being exceded or the cURL time limit is expiring?

Comment: The PHP time limit is being exceeded. I can so many other CURL requests but this one (PUT) times out.

Comment: @Chuck what happens if you add this line: `curl_setopt(CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Length: '.filesize($file_path_str), 'Connection: close'));`?

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I figured it out. It was the `fclose($fh_res)`: I should have been calling that after `curl_exec` and not before.

Comment: Oh yeh, I didn't spot that - obvious when you point it out. I'm still surprised it was hanging and not just dying with an error - one to watch out for.

Answer (score 0):

If you are absolutely sure that the connection is being timed out and nothing else.. then you can add the following lines of code-

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 1000);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10000 );
```