# curl statement to PHP enabling use of Apache TIKA

Tags: php, apache, curl, apache-tika

I have installed `Apache TIKA` and `TIKAJAXRS`

I intend to use it with PHP (TIKA as a service). I need to extract contents of a URL and then manipulate the returned contents. To use TIKA as a service, the documentation says

It is possible to use a remote file with `TikaJAXRS` by downloading it via its URL first then piping it to the appropriate service:

```
$ curl -s "http://url/to/my.file" | curl -X PUT -T - <<TIKA ADDRESS>>/meta
$ curl -s "http://url/to/my.file" | curl -X PUT -T -<<TIKA ADDRESS>>/tika
```

I am unable to translate the above statements to PHP using PHP cURL.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [PHP curl tutorial](http://php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php), [this Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7340809/php-curl-put-from-file-path) and the [Apache Tika Server documentation](http://wiki.apache.org/tika/TikaJAXRS), what you should be doing is something like:

```
// Set where to connect to
$ch = curl_init("http://localhost:9998/meta");
// Request will be a PUT
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PUT, 1);
// Set the file to send
$file_path_str = "/path/to/my/file.txt";
$fh_res = fopen($file_path_str, 'r');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILE, $fh_res);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, filesize($file_path_str));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
// Send the request
$curl_response_res = curl_exec ($ch);
fclose($fh_res);

// Do something with the result
echo "<p>Tika says:</p>";
echo "<pre>" + $curl_response_res + "</pre>";
```