# Why does this PHP Curl PUT Request returns Code 500?

Tags: php, curl, put, http-status-code-500

I try to connect the following API via Curl (PHP): https://wiki.vg/Mojang_API#Example

I was successful with other CURL Requests, just the PUT request doesnt work.

I'm working on XAMPP, but I also tried the code on my server with the same result. The following Curl command works like a charm locally and on my server:

```
curl -X PUT -H "Authorization: Bearer [authtoken]" -F model=alex -F file="@test.png;type=image/png" https://api.mojang.com/user/profile/32143e660e624cd8b05b889f0af49e39/skin -i
```

However, if I try to convert this to PHP, I get error 400 or 500. I browser other threads the whole day without any result. This here is the raw code without all the other tests I tried:

```
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');
        
        $post = array(
            'model' => 'alex',
            'file' => '\"@test.png;type=image/png\"'
        );
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
        
        $headers = array(
            $this->accessToken
        );
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        var_dump(curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE));
        curl_close($ch);
```

Some further notes:

- yes I'm sure Curl is installed since other API requests work
- yes I'm sure the auth token works, it works in other requests
- I recognized the payload requests the file as raw image file data and I pull over the png name - not sure if this is supposed to work

Comment: That's not the correct way to upload a file. See https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.curlfile.php

Comment: Although I'm not sure that's the right way to do it with PUT, maybe it's only for POST.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7340809/php-curl-put-from-file-path

Answer (score 0):

Ok that went quicker then I expected it. Should have asked easlier today.

I tried Curlfile before, but it looks like I did something wrong.

This comment from Barmer helped:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.curlfile.php

Thanks ^^